# In XEN how can I check if guest is HVM or PVH?

Tags: xen

Xen supports various visualizations e.g. para virtualizastion and full hardware visualization. How can I know the type of visualization for running guest?

Comment: Here is your answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/511923/determine-which-guest-is-running-on-xen-hvm-or-pv-guest